# XML filter is applied to non-XML value

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I am just starting to learn js and need your help.

I have following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function () { 
            $('.test1').(function(){
                    this.each(function () {
                    var a = $(this);
                    alert(a);
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<pre class="test1">
blabla1
blabla2
blabla3
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

With this code I wanted to find out how "each" will split the content of the pre-tag. Firebug returns following error message:

> XML filter is applied to non-XML value

The error is caused by this command:

```
$('.test1').(function(){...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to see how `.each` works in your example, change code to:

```
$(function () { 
    $('.test1').each(function(){
        var a = $(this);
        alert(a.html());
    });
});
```

However, like @James_Johnson said earlier, the code in `.each` function will only execute once, so you are likely to see

```
blabla1
blabla2
blabla3
```

in your alert message

To make `.each` iterate, you have to do sth like

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
                $(function () { 
                    $('.test1 p').each(function(){
                       var a = $(this);
                       alert(a.html());
                    });
                });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre class="test1">
           <p>blabla1</p>
           <p>blabla2</p>
           <p>blabla3</p>
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing inside of the `<pre>` tag is text, so there's no need for `each()` in this case. Try something like this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(function (){  
        alert($(".test1").text());
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the text broken down, you can try this.

```
$.each( $('.test1').text().split('\n'), function(index,value){ 
    alert( value ); 
});
```